# Creative Sound Blaster Recon3D PCIe 5.1 Sound Troubles after Reboot/Standy

Tags: audio, sound-card, surround-sound, creative

My Problem:

If you Stand-By/Hibernate/Shutdown my PC and reboot/wake it up, i got strange sound.
Then sound is without Bass (and Sound in Battlefield 3 sounds weird, maybe just because of the missing bass).

My Solution:

I open the Control Panel (Creative; it starts automatically with Windows) and uncheck any Option the sound gets fixed (bass get activated)

My Questions:

1. Does anyone have the same problems? Or Solutions?
2. Are there alternative drivers for this card which i can try (like "daniel_k"-Drivers for Creative X-Fi Cards)

My Setup:

- Sound Blaster Recon3D PCIe Systemsteuerung, release 1.02.22
- Cooler Master CM Storm Sirus 5.1 Gaming Headset
- Windows 7 Ultimate (64 bit)
- All Updates installed (Windows, Nvidia-Drivers, Intel-Drivers, Creative-Drivers, ...)
- Mainboard: ASUS P8Z77-V Deluxe
- CPU: Intel i7-3770k (not overclocked)

Any help and ideas are appreciated!

Comment: i believe there is a new set of drivers available for your sound card. Perform a CLEAN install, using DriverSweeper.   http://support.creative.com/scripts/getprod.aspx?id=20835

Comment: @AlanTuring nope, i have the PCIe version...